# Notifications with SignalR2 and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to build a menu notification with SignalR 2 in my MVC app.

So, when some user do a specific action, some others users (not all and not the same every time) must be notified. Some like the SO notification when somebody answer a question.

Do I should store the connectionId in a database to know who must be notified after the action is triggered? What would you do?

Comment: It's up to you how well you can manage your users. In one of my recent project I used browser SessionID to identify my users and and keep them in a static list as online users. Then if a user want to send a notification another user I use this static list to identify the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar and this is what I did:

1) Define notification types based on user roles. Each notification type had a list of specific recipients. That way I knew if a notification type was created I had to notify certain users.

2) I send the notifications by name, not by connection id.

3) Notifications can be sent from client code (JS) or from back-end code (C#). In JS you have functions like "others" that are really handy. In C# you have "others" too but that only works with connection ids.

4) I'm notifying changes in the data too so if someone is changing order 1, I notify a supervisor and any other user that has the order opened (in this case I send the notification to the supervisor and all the other agents and based on the order each user has opened I decide if I handle the msg or not).

I hope this helps!